# debugging a function in R that was not exported by a package

Tags: debugging, r

I would like to step through, using `debug()` or `trace()`, a function that was not exported. For example, how can I do it for `vcov.polr` of the package `MASS`, which is called from the function `polr`. `polr` is exported, but vcov.polr is not.

That is, when I run `polr`, I would like the debug browser to start once the code enters `vcov.polr`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try

```
debug(MASS:::vcov.polr)
```

note that three colon `:::` make the hidden object in a package visible.