# Model namespaces in code completion with R - or how to organize R code

Tags: r, namespaces, code-completion, tab-completion

This is more of a general code structuring question.

At the moment I try to write my code into "namespaces". So for example, I would have:

```
Mine.FancyPlot.Plot(...)
Mine.FancyPlot.Impl.PlotCanvas(...)
Mine.FancyPlot.Impl.PlotLegend(...)
Mine.BasicPlot.Plot(...)
Mine.BasicPlot.Impl.PlotCanvas(...)
Mine.BasicPlot.Impl.PlotLegend(...)
Mine.BasicPlot.Impl.PlotLines(...)
```

The idea is that I am trying to hide away "private" functions in a "Impl" for implementation namespace. So outside of `Mine_FancyPlot.R` I wouldn't call `Mine.FancyPlot.Impl` functions.

This approach works reasonably well, except code completion isn't as nice as it could be.

To begin with, when I type `Mine.BasicPlot.` and hit `TAB`, I get all functions, including the `Impl` functions, and because `I` is before `P`, they even hide the "public" user functions.

So I started changing the structure to

```
MyPub.FancyPlot.Plot(...)
MyPriv.FancyPlot.PlotCanvas(...)
MyPriv.FancyPlot.PlotLegend(...)
MyPub.BasicPlot.Plot(...)
MyPriv.Mine.BasicPlot.PlotCanvas(...)
MyPriv.Mine.BasicPlot.PlotLegend(...)
MyPriv.Mine.BasicPlot.PlotLines(...)
```

This works better in that "private" functions are no longer predicted. However, I still have the issue that if I type `MyPub.` and hit `TAB`, I can't actually see all different "namespaces" (such as I would in `Java`, `C++`, ...), but rather a long list of functions starting all in the first "namespace".

Ideally, I'd like code completion in `R` to cut off all predictions at the next dot, and unique them, so Ideally when I type `MyPub.` and hit `TAB`, I would only get a list of "sub-namespaces" and functions in `MyPub`.

Is this possible? Can the code prediction be altered to reflect this behaviour? Or is there a better way to achieve what I am aiming for?

Comment: It would maybe be easier to take the functions you use and place them in a package. You can then export the functions you wish the user to have access to. If your functions are members of a class you can write bespoke completion for them using .DollarNames. See ?.DollarNames

Comment: You could also consider using s3 classes jeres, since it looks like you're basically trying to just call plot on a bunch of different types of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider putting your functions in a package to organise them. Functions that are not exported will only be accessible by doing 'package:::functionNotExported' and will not be listed when just doing 'functionNotExpo[tab]'

See for instance [debugging a function in R that was not exported by a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625224/debugging-a-function-in-r-that-was-not-exported-by-a-package)