# Debugging into and changing R-functions in packages

Tags: r

To illustrate my question I am using a function of the TSclust package for example as follows:

```
test<-function()
{

    # this works just fine
    require(TSclust)
    ns  <- 100
    z1  <- rnorm(ns) 
    z2  <- rnorm(ns)
    res <- diss.CDM(z1, z2, type = "min")
}
```

This works just fine. Now I want to see the function diss.CMD by typing
the function 'diss.CDM' into the R-editor yielding:

```
function (x, y, type = "min") 
{
  .ts.sanity.check(x, y)
  comp <- .compression.lengths(x, y, type)
  comp$cxy/(comp$cx + comp$cy)
}
<environment: namespace:TSclust>
```

From this I create my own personal copy such as:

```
myDiss<- function (x, y, type = "min") 
{
  .ts.sanity.check(x, y)
  comp <- .compression.lengths(x, y, type)
  comp$cxy/(comp$cx + comp$cy)
}
```

Calling myDiss in the R-code above as follows

```
res <- myDiss(z1, z2, type = "min")
```

let's me debug into the code. However the R-session does neither understand 
the function  **".ts.sanity.check"**  nor compression length **".compression.lengths"**.

Is there a way to load this function and make my personal copy work?

Comment: I have summarized a few possibilities to debug functions in R: http://blog.haunschmid.name/debugging-in-r/ (I would use the option descirbed by @leosz in his/her answer). The problem you describe comes from the fact that .ts.sanity.check is probably a hidden function of TSclust. You can either (1) look for that method in their code base  and (a) download the R package and add the two functions to your workspace , (b) create an R project in RStudio with their code base or (2) use another debugging option where you don't need their code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the whole codebase for the package from the [TSclust github repository](https://github.com/cran/TSclust) and debugg using that.

Or maybe a simpler way is to do as described in this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625224/debugging-a-function-in-r-that-was-not-exported-by-a-package?rq=1)

Which is something like:

```
require(TSclust)
ns  <- 100
z1  <- rnorm(ns) 
z2  <- rnorm(ns)
debug(diss.CDM)
res <- diss.CDM(z1, z2, type = "min")
```